# Regular expression - write language in MSO

Tags: logic, regular-language

> $$(ab^*a)^*$$ (a) Define this language in MSO
>   (b) Decide if this language is definable in first order logic

(b) It seems to be simple. We know that we can't distinguish in $n$ rounds (wit $n$ quantifiers) two linear order with length $2^{n}+1$ and $2^{n}+2$. These two order can be encoded to two words:   $a^{2^{n}+1}$ and $2^{2^{n}+2}$. Then we use formula for words to distinguish these two words (becase exactly one of them belongs to langugage).

(a)I know that it may be said:

- first consistent block of $a$ has odd length
- last consistent block of $a$ has odd length
- for each symbol $b$ there are exists two $a$ on the left and on the right
- if between two consistent block of $b$ there are exists some symbol $a$ then there is even number of $a$ in this block

However, writing this as formula MSO is hard for me. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following big hammers:

(1) MSO captures exactly the regular languages (Büchi).

(2) FO captures exactly the [star-free languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star-free_language) (McNaughton). See also the more detailed page [Langage sans étoile](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langage_sans_%C3%A9toile).

(3) A regular language is star-free if and only if its [syntactic monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_monoid) is [aperiodic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aperiodic_semigroup) (Schützenberger). Again, for the syntactic monoid, you can also look at the French version [Monoïde syntaxique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono%C3%AFde_syntaxique).

For your language $L = (ab^*a)^*$, the transitions of the minimal automaton are
\begin{array}
 &   &1  &2\\
 a  &2  &1\\
 b  &0  &2
\end{array}
and the initial and unique final state is $1$. Its syntactic monoid has 7 elements: $M = \{1, a, b, ab, ba, aba, bab, 0\}$ and is presented by the relations $a^2 = 1$, $b^2 = b$, $bab = 0$. The fact that $a^2 = 1$ shows immediately that $M$ is not aperiodic, and hence $L$ is not $FO$-expressible.

To get a MSO-formula for $L$, you need to specify the properties of the set $X_q$ of positions of the word in which you are in state $q$ ($q = 1, 2$). The formula should be something like this, where of course, $\min$, $\max$ and $x+1$ should be rewritten with FO-formulas:
\begin{align}
  \exists X_1 \ \exists X_2\ \ &X_1 \cap X_2 = \emptyset  \wedge  \forall x\ (x \in  X_1 \vee x \in X_2)\\
 &(\min \in X_1) \wedge (\max \in X_1) \wedge  {}\\
 &(x \in X_1 \wedge \mathbf{a}x) \to (x+1 \in X_2) \wedge  {}\\
  &(x \in X_2 \wedge \mathbf{a}x) \to (x+1 \in X_1) \wedge  {} \\
&(x \in X_2 \wedge \mathbf{b}x) \to (x+1 \in X_2) 
\end{align}

Comment: I am going to parse your solution in a next hour and give you a sign about effect, but at this moment: What about my approach to (b) ? And what does it mean star free ? totally zero number of stars? When it comes to Buchi theorem I know it, @J.-E. Pin

Comment: See the links I provided for the definition of star-free.

Comment: Ahh ok, so only at this moment try to overthrow my approach to (b) please, however I am going to overthrow your solution!

Comment: I have some problems with "for each symbol $b$ there are exists two $a$
on the left and on the right". What about $abbba$?

Comment: But I ask for checking part (b)

Comment: Sorry. You can indeed show that the language is not first-order definable by using game-theoretic arguments.

Comment: So my argument works (for (b))?

Comment: So does it mean that general method is: find automat, translate it to MSO (for example - number of states = number of subsets, rules ~= transitions), yeah ? The question is: Is it importan to consider syntatic monoid to only translate regular expression to MSO

Comment: Can you help me here ? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2152224/write-formula-in-mso-expressing-that-graph-is-grid-many-variants  Very important for me before exam (today :) )

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** Guess a subset of the $\mathtt a$s that you pretend are $\mathtt c$s instead, and recognize $(\mathtt a \mathtt b^* \mathtt c)^*$.

Comment: $(ab^*c)^*$ can be recognized in first order logic: $\forall_x [(a(x) \to b(x+1) \vee c(x+1)) \wedge (b(x)\to (b(x+1) \vee c(x+1)) \wedge (c(x) \to (a(x+1) \vee (\forall_y y\le x)))]$. $+1$ denotes next position. It means be expressed in first order logic using $\le$ (successor)

Comment: What about (b) ?

Comment: Indeed, the hint does not really help...

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Am I right that this language can be recognized by First order logic ? After all, it contains star!

Comment: @haskell-fun You are right, and this language is star-free, but is not so easy to give a star-free expression for it.

Comment: Ahh, ok in last years I did some things as flattening nested stars in regular expressions:)

Comment: This is a bit different for star-free expressions, since complementation is allowed.